# Definition of category of functions $X \to Y$

Tags: category-theory

In *Categories for the Working Mathematician*, by MacLane, p. 105:

> For example, take $C$ to be the category of functions $f: X \to Y$. Here, a monomorphism $g \to f$ is a function $g: S \to T$ between a pair of subsets $S \subset Y$ and $T \subset Y$ such that $g(s) = f(s)$ for all $s \in S$. This means that the diagram
>
> $$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} S @>{g}>> T\\ @VVV @VVV
> \\ X @>{f}>> Y \end{CD}$$
> commutes.

How is this category defined exactly (objects and morphisms) ? If the objects are functions $X \to Y$, then $g$ is not a member of $C$ for example.

Comment: Presumably the lower arrow was meant to be $f$ as  $g$ does not map $X$ to $Y$ (and that's what the words before the diagram would require).

Comment: It is, thank you.

Comment: The vertical arrows are both the inclusion map and $g$ is the restriction of $f$ to $S$.

Comment: Almost certainly off topic... But I wonder, if you let $X$ and $Y$ be fixed topological spaces, and let morphisms $\operatorname{Hom}(f, g)$ be homotopies from $f$ to $g$, modulo homotopy of homotopies, then would that ever be an interesting category to study?  (Obviously, it's a groupoid, but otherwise...)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Sure, that’s the fundamental groupoid of the mapping space $X^Y,$ which is basically the information of $\pi_0$ and all the $\pi_1$s of this space. If you allow $X$ and $Y$ to vary you have the homotopy $(2,1)$-category of spaces, which is natural to study though not as well known as the homotopy $1$-category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably, the objects are triples $(X,Y,f)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are sets, and $f$ is a function $X\to Y$. Then, morphisms between two objects $(X_1,Y_1,f_1)$ and $(X_2,Y_2,f_2)$ are pairs $(s,t)$ of functions $s\colon X_1\to X_2$ and $t\colon Y_1\to Y_2$ such that the diagram
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} X_1 @>{f_1}>> Y_1\\ @V{s}VV @V{t}VV
\\ X_2 @>{f_2}>> Y_2 \end{CD}$$
commutes.

---

Alternatively, it may be thought of as the functor category $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathbf2,\mathrm{Sets})$, where $\mathbf2$ is the category with two objects and one (non-identity) morphism $0\to 1$. Then, the image of the diagram $0\to 1$ in $\mathrm{Sets}$ will look like $X\xrightarrow{f}Y$, and naturality exactly translates into the commutativity of the diagram above.